# Register Form in several steps

Tags: session, symfony, fosuserbundle

I face a problem with a Form in several step.
I would like create a register form in many steps (3-4), and then save my FOSUser at the last step.
The principle would be to create an empty User in step 1, and fill it part by part until the last step.

My problem is that it's not recommended to store object in session.
So, I wanted to know if Symfony2 proposed an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the data of the previous steps in hidden fields and submit it with every step again.

Why do you thing saving objects in the sessions is not good? If you write proper serialization handlers this should not be a big problem.

Entites are indeed a bit problematic to store in the session (i had problems with that as well) but you could create a delegate object containing only the user inputs and store that in the session and then after the last step build a symfony user object out of it. Just be sure not to leave masses of unused objects in the session.